# How do I output the % complete of resque-status?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, redis, resque

I'm using resque-status for Resque/Redis...

https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status

I basically want to create a new Sinatra method .. something like below. I only have 2 JobsWithStatus so it could either return both or a specific one, i dont really care.

```
post '/getstatus' do
  # return status here of all kinds (or specific)
end
```

Then I want to output the % complete via jquery on the frontend using a polling timer that checks the status every 5 seconds.

This is what I have

```
post '/refresh' do
  job_id = PostSaver.create(:length => Forum.count)
  status = Resque::Status.get(job_id)
  redirect '/'
end
```

It says in the documentation i can just use status.pct_complete but it always returns 0? Even then, I'm new to ruby and even IF the variable showed the proper % complete, I'm not sure how to make that variable work inside of a separate sinatra entry (in /getstatus rather than /refresh).

I tried this however and it keeps returning 0

```
post '/refresh' do
  job_id = PostSaver.create(:length => Forum.count)
  status = Resque::Status.get(job_id)
  sleep 20
  status.pct_complete.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw your question over on reddit…

To have the status come back as something other than 0, you need to use the `at` ([http://rubydoc.info/github/quirkey/resque-status/master/Resque/JobWithStatus:at](http://rubydoc.info/github/quirkey/resque-status/master/Resque/JobWithStatus%3aat)) method to set a percentage during the calculation you're running.

You probably don't want `sleep` calls inside an action. The timer should be in jQuery.

---

Sharing Status

```
post '/refresh' do
  job_id = PostSaver.create(:length => Forum.count)
  status = Resque::Status.get(job_id)
  sleep 20
  "{'percent_complete':#{status.pct_complete},'job_id':'#{job_id}'}"
end
```

Then in whatever is getting the status (some jQuery#ajax call?), you can grab the job_id from the returned JSON and then with your next request, you might do something like:

```
post '/status' do
  status = Resque::Status.get(params['job_id'])
  "{'percent_complete':#{status.pct_complete}}"
end
```

Comment: By the way the sleep was just as a test to give the %age time to not be 0, I'm going to have that in a separate sinatra method. This is a basic question about how do i make the 'status' variable in the '/refresh' method available somewhere else, like the '/getstatus' method?

Comment: Generally you are not going to be sharing variables between actions. The exception would be if you were rendering an action from another (which may not be a thing you can even do in sinatra) Since it's ruby, you can always define a status method of some sort and just call out to that. I'll edit something in so you can see what I mean.

Comment: One more thing, is it possible for me to get ALL jobswithstatus, without having to do .get(:job_id)? I only have 2 job queues, and one worker, and instead of storing the UUID to a db to retrive later I was hoping i could just get all active jobswithstatus and filter them that way (name, time created, status, queued?, etc). I know its kind of nonconventional i suppose but this is just my first app

Comment: That's a fairly common thing to want to do. `Resque::Status.statuses` will return an array of the actual jobs. `Resque::Status.status_ids` will return an array of the ids. `Resque.redis.keys("status:*")` will give you a similar list using redis directly, though the keys will be prepended with “status”.

I'd suggest poking at the source for Resque and Resque::Status. Lots of fun stuff in there.

Comment: WTF. I just spent so long doing it an alternative method. I looked all over their site for that........ ARLWEKGJWEGEWG. That could have saved me like hours trying to figure this out :| Thanks so much for that...

Comment: Ah, the beauty of just looking at the source code. :) Took me about 30s of git cloning and 20s of grep'ing to find the answer (and 2y of working with resque to know that would be the fastest way to find the answer). :)